# Is "on someone's view" standard among academic philosophers?

Tags: terminology

I've recently seen the phrase *on his or her view* used by two philosophers to mean "according to him or her" — for example, "On Frick's view, we have a disjunctive definition." The phrase seems odd — how can something be *on* a view? Is it in common use among philosophers?

Answer (score 1):

It might need more context, but if it isn't a typo, then I'd take "on" to be short for "based on". Frick might not have expressed a view about this particular question, but might have some wider view within which this "disjunctive definition" would make sense. Thus you might paraphrase it as, "Based on Frick's approach, we have..." But it's more likely to be a typo.

Edit: I've just realized you've seen it twice, so maybe it isn't a typo. In which case, the interpretation I've made is probably what the writer had in mind.

Comment: In a similar vein, "My opinions on someone's view are..." is a way of introducing counterpoints, commentary, etc. *on* someone else's view.

Answer (score 0):

In [someone]'s view is more common than on [someone]'s view, but both are used.

As an example, see this [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=On+Kant%27s+view%2Cin+Kant%27s+view&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2COn%20Kant%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20Kant%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20Kant%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cin%20Kant%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20Kant%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20Kant%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0) using Kant as an example.

Similarly, here is one using [Einstein](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=On+Einstein%27s+view%2CIn+Einstein%27s+View&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20Einstein%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CIn%20Einstein%20%27s%20View%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20Einstein%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20Einstein%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0).

But, I could not plot Obama. And Bush only resulted with [*in Bush's view](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=On+Bush%27s+view%2CIn+Bush%27s+view&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CIn%20Bush%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20Bush%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20Bush%20%27s%20view%3B%2Cc0) plotting.

So, it seems to skew toward philosophical usage (some scientific) but not political.